# Why is the flashing light asynchron to the shots fired at Brett in Pulp Fiction?

Tags: reference, pulp-fiction, quentin-tarantino, rear-window

A few days ago I watched Pulp Fiction again. I noticed something and now I'm curious about a little detail. When Vincent and Jules killing Brett in Pulp Fiction a yellow/orange light appears two times but they fire definitive more than two shots.

In Rear Window (1954) Jeff repeatedly sets off his camera flashbulbs, temporarily blinding Thorwald. And the light when Thorwald gets blinded looks like the flashing light in Pulp Fiction.

Maybe that's a reference but doesn't answer the question why the flashing light in Pulp Fiction is asynchron to the shots fired at Brett.

Pulp Fiction scene: http://youtube.com/watch?v=PE9Qm8mShik

Rear Window scene: http://youtube.com/watch?v=oowcsynjIwc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fascinating question!

According to the [Pulp Fiction Movie Reference Guide](http://wiki.tarantino.info/index.php/Pulp_Fiction_Movie_References_Guide), this scene is actually a direct homage to the 1946 film [The Killers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killers_%281946_film%29), "an American film noir directed by Robert Siodmak and based in part on the short story of the same name by Ernest Hemingway."

The entry for "The Killers" reads:

> The Killers (1946): The killing of Brett mirrors the killing of Swede
>   in 'The Killers', including flashing lights and the shot of the two
>   hitmen firing their weapons.

So it seems that the flashing lights are *not* in reference to Rear Window, but are an homage to The Killers.

Comment: Look at the big brain on @AndrewMartin!